# Holding sending reset password emails until some indecator devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise

I have a `PasswordController` inherit from `Devise::PasswordsController`, I made a `create` function that helps me to send user reset password notification email, its implementation:

```
  def create
    # I need to put some condition on the next line
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      render :json => "Request successfully sent"
    else
      render :json => resource.errors, :status => 422
    end
  end
```

It works fine but if user clicked on reset password 5 times 5 emails will be sent to him (If a delay happened or something **users never waits, they need fast resposne**) and the last one will only work, So I want to disable sending email until this token expired or something, I searched about it but couldn't find anything, I thought about make a new attribute inside user table which will be a `datetime` to indicate when was the last time the email has been sent but i'm asking if there is a better way to make using devise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`user.reset_password_period_valid?`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb#L77-L79)

```
def reset_password_period_valid?
  reset_password_sent_at && reset_password_sent_at.utc >= self.class.reset_password_within.ago.utc
end
```

This is essentially exactly the implementation you were suggesting; but it's already built-in if you're using the `Rcoverable` devise module!